# where do i put the seekbarprogress method to position the seekbar correctly?

Tags: java, android, xml, seekbar

Hi guys i have a seekbar a textview and a plus and a minus button. the seekbar can be used to set the value of the textview between 0 and 10. I have also implemented an onclicklistener for the plus and minus button so that when they are pressed the plus button adds 1 to the value and the minus takes away a one from the value. everything works fine as i can use the seekbar to edit the value and then i can use the buttons to edit the textview value from where the seekbar stopped so for example if i used the seekbar to get to 5 i can then use the buttons to get to 9 however when i have used the button to edit the value the seekbar becomes out of position as it remains in the same position when i last touched it. So were do i put the seekbarprogress method so it updates the seekbar position of where the value stopped when using the button to update the textview value so that when i come back to using the seekbar it is in the right position of when i last used the button?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set progress of the seek bar in the onclick method of the buttons...i.e. after adding/subtracting whatever new value you get set the same to seekbar via 
setProgress method.